# Steerable pyramid filter

Tags: python, image-processing, filtering

I am trying to understand what this code snippet used in creating steerable pyramid does:

```
th1[np.where(self.AT[i] - k*np.pi/self.K < -np.pi)] += 2.*np.pi
th1[np.where(self.AT[i] - k*np.pi/self.K > np.pi)] -= 2.*np.pi
ind_ = np.where(np.absolute(th1 - k*np.pi/self.K) <= np.pi/2.)
fil_[ind_] = self.ALPHAK * (np.cos(th1[ind_] - k*np.pi/self.K))**(self.K-1)
```

(full code in https://github.com/TetsuyaOdaka/SteerablePyramid/blob/master/steerable_pyramid.py (rows 267-270)

I understand that it creates half of a mask for constructing the directional filter, but as the first row doesn't rotate all grid points, just some, in two sets, and then uses indexes to create the mask like part of a circle, but clearly in some way that obeys the constraints needeed by radial and angular decomposition (https://www.cns.nyu.edu/pub/eero/simoncelli95b.pdf).

But I have very hard time understanding how this actually works. Could someone help explaining these lines?

- `self.AT` is angles in grid that has been converted from cartesian to polar coordinate system
- `k` is the numerator of the rotation (basically direction)
- `self.K` is the denominator (into how many sections circle has been cut)
  `ALPHAK` is normalization factor (though the reasoning behind it is beyond me)

(The algorithm seems to take everything from here http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2014/79/article.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are working in polar coordinate system which have angels that are between (-pi, pi]. Polar coordinate is not a unique mapping every angle is the same if you add to it 2 * pi.

This means that points with angle that are more then pi or less then -pi will need to be mapped to (-pi, pi].

You find the points which are close to a direction, `k * np.pi/self.K`, by measuring the distance `self.AT[i] - k * np.pi/self.K`.

But the points which have `self.AT[i] - k*np.pi/self.K < -np.pi` or `self.AT[i] - k * np.pi/self.K > np.pi` will not be mapped correctly to the range (-pi, pi].

So the first two lines are only meant to correct the mapping by remap the points back to (-pi, pi] so when you use in the third line the condition `np.where(np.absolute(th1 - k*np.pi/self.K) <= np.pi/2` all the angles will be mapped correctly

The line `ind_ = np.where(np.absolute(th1 - k*np.pi/self.K) <= np.pi/2.)` is just getting all the index of points that are pi/2 away from the direction k*np.pi/self.K.

The last line is calculating filter values for those points.